# Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite' that satisfies the version constraints:

Tags: android, react-native, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java, logrocket

I am facing an error while building an android app with react-native, If anyone has an idea then help me out.

```
Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:{strictly [3.0, 4.0[}.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :logrocket_react-native
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite' that satisfies the version constraints:
```

This is my logrocket version:

```
"@logrocket/react-native": "1.6.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with LogRocket support about this and they just got back and said they've released version 1.11.1 which tightens up the dependency on protobuf and fixes this. Release notes here: https://docs.logrocket.com/docs/mobile-sdk-changelog#1111-2023-01-31

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that version is broken. There needs to be someone on their team to fix their dependency, but on the meantime you can override the version of protobuf-javalite that it is using.

Our team has found a hotfix open /node_modules/@logrocket/react-native/android/build.gradle

and make this change[image]

```
        version {
            strictly '[3.0, 21['
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just started getting the same issue on native Android today.

> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:{strictly [3.0, 4.0[; prefer 3.19.1}.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.logrocket:logrocket:1.11.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.22.0-RC1.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.22.0-RC1/protobuf-javalite-3.22.0-RC1.pom
> > Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-parent:3.22.0-RC1.

Tried upping and downgrading logrocket version, checking out a commit in my project from when it was still working, etc, but it's still bugged. Seems like an issue from logrocket.

Comment: can you please tell me earlier which version you were using?

Comment: We were at version 1.10.1 when it used to work yesterday, according to the docs the newest version is 1.11.0, neither of them are compiling successfully.

Comment: The same thing happened to me also I am using the 1.6.2 version yesterday it was fine but today this issue is coming.

Comment: I didn't change anything related to npm libraries or native android, Yesterday I just changed styles in code, and today, when I am building or generating APK this error, is throwing to me. After comment out logrocket, the project is working.

Comment: Let me know if you found anything.

Comment: Affecting us too. I just hit up their support to see if they have a solution (or even know about the issue).

Comment: They responded back pretty quickly. They determined it's a widespread issue with protobuf in general (see here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/11719#issuecomment-1410586339). They're working on a fix to mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, tried setting protobuf version between 3.0 to 4.0, cleared cache, re-built the app, still no luck. Disabled log-rocket for now, till a solution is found.

Comment: Same here, I didn't change anything regarding npm or native android, but today it is giving me an error.

Comment: Let me know If you found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by protobuf issue: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/11719

For anyone affected by this due to the LogRocket SDK, the LogRocket team has stated that they are attempting to mitigate the issue from their side.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue from past one day. Changing the version strictly [3.0, 4.0[ to strictly '3.19.1'in Firebase in Nodemodules->logRocket->android->build.gradle and creating a patch package for it worked for me now.